# Get product from advanced search page by attribute value

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, products, advanced-search

I am trying to programatically retrieve a list of products that have a attribute with a specific value.

i am working on **advanced search page**.

i have created two attribute

1. **price_foreach**
2. **quantity**

1) if customer enter **price from 100 to 150** and left **blank quantity** than it will show all products from price_foreach 100 to 150 its working fine

2) but if customers enter **price_foreach 100 to 150** and **quantity 100** it should show all product from 100 to 150 but in respect of quantity it should respect 100 and more than 100 products.

Comment: you can refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1338795

Comment: @GopalPatel thanks... i refers but where should i edit  i did not get can you please tell me where should i edit it. while i am working on advanced search page.

Comment: Update your question what exactly you want to do with advanced search.

Comment: i have created two attribute 1) price_foreach 2) quantity 1) if customer enter price from 100 to 150 and left blank quantity than it will show all products from price_foreach 100 to 150 its working fine 2) but if customers enter price_foreach 100 to 150 and quantity 100 it should show all product from 100 to 150 but in respect of quantity it should respect 100 and more than 100 products.

Comment: what do you mean by "it should respect 100 and more than 100 products" ?

Comment: @GopalPatel "it should respect 100 and more than 100 products"  it should show product who have assigned attribute value quantity 100 or more than 100